# Spinning 3D WebGL Shapes

Tags: javascript, html, webgl

I am supposed to draw a transparent sphere which can be rotated by mouse dragging. I tried to start learning the basis of WebGl but I have not found any appropriate sources. Can anybody help me how to start learning WebGl and also how to draw 3D shapes such as Sphere or tetrahedron and how I can spin it in all dimensions ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you use [three.js](http://threejs.org) but if you really want to learn WebGL start with http://webglfundamentals.org ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a framework like three.js that abstracts webGL's functionality, it makes doing things like this a breeze. Check out threejs.org and  http://learningthreejs.com/